# oledb exception was unhandled in c# Data type mismatch in criteria expression

Tags: c#, database, oledb

```
foreach (object selectedItem in lstProjectMemberID.SelectedItems)
{
    DataRowView dr = (DataRowView)selectedItem;
    String result = dr["user_id"].ToString();
    int intResult = int.Parse(result);

    cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO project_users(project_id,user_id) VALUES (@newProjID.Text,@userID)";
    cmd.Parameters.Add(newProjID.Text, OleDbType.Integer).Value = newProjID.Text;
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userID", intResult);

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

 }
```

i have this code and im getting the error Data type mismatch in criteria expression. on this part cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); :( what will i do?

i think i am wrong with my insert query command because of the intresult

Answer (score 1):

That looks strange, change the parameter name from `@newProjID.Text` to `@newProjID`:

```
cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO project_users(project_id,user_id) VALUES (@newProjID,@userID)";
cmd.Parameters.Add("@newProjID", OleDbType.Integer).Value = newProjID.Text;
```

But if `newProjID.Text` is a string you should parse it to an `int` first:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@newProjID", OleDbType.Integer).Value = int.Parse(newProjID.Text);
```